# Horizontal Accordion - jQuery plugin - scrolling animation bug on Firefox - how to debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

There is a plug-in for jQuery that allows you to build horizontal accordions, it works great in all browsers except firefox.  My main problem is that I'm somewhat unfamiliar with debugging client side code, I'm a Java programmer mostly, although I do have a good understanding of client technologies, actually trying to debug this issue leaves me lost, could someone please look at the bug, if possible determine the root cause, and share how they approached the issue?

[I've already set up a reproduction of the code, the gray bars are "handles" click them to expand their content, light gray means already expanded, dark gray means minimized](http://jsfiddle.net/GJYVE/21/)

when I refer to the accordion I mean the full component, in this case, the two handles, and the content that is shown

Here are some things I already know to get you started:

- during the animation the size of the accordion increases by 1 or 2 pixels
- the bug is obvious when the containing div has a size set to the size of the accordion
- if the size of the containing div is increased the size still increases producing a "quivering effect" of the rightmost edge
- the problem is only present on firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting the CSS a bit ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJYVE/22/)):

```
#containingDiv {
    height : 200px;
    width : 460px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#myAccordion {
    width: 2000px; /* should be wide enough to contain all panels - max width in opera is 32766 */
}
```

---

Update: After referring to the [standard CSS for the hrzAccordion](http://www.portalzine.de/index?/Horizontal_Accordion--print#colored_fe1131f55561ce78ff3ba97923c3a89f), I discovered that adding a negative right margin to the handle fixed all flickering problems ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJYVE/35/)):

```
.handle {
    height : 200px;
    width : 30px;
    background : #aaaaaa;
    margin : 0 -1px 0 0;
    padding : 0px;
}
```

Comment: my 3rd bullet point addresses this, although I modified the containing div, and not the accordion, the problem still persists as you can see the right side "quivers" in your updated example.  So, you kind of worked around the issue as I did for deployment, but I'm more interested in debugging it, and finding out what is the actual problem

Comment: Doesn't quiver at all for me in FF3.6, so it looks like a pretty nice fix.

Comment: great, the updated example is now working in firefox, nice job.  I'm still very interested as to the root cause of this issue, as the actual solution seems somewhat unintuitive

Comment: The problem is due to the width of the content sharing it's width with the handle. It ends up being slightly wider when added together thus pushing the content to the next line (the float makes it do that). If you look at the original demo and change the animation time to something like 10000, you'll see it "flicker" due to the content being pushed to the next line, then back up, then down, etc etc... adding the negative margin allows both the handle and the content to fit together not cause the content to be pushed down - either that or it a computer goblin making your life miserable :P